# What must I update in this LLBLGen-reliant code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, llblgenpro, syncfusion

I updated some broken references in a solution (new computer, reintroducing a large solution to its 3rd party components and to TFS).

I'm down from a starting point of 11,257 errors to only a few dozen. The first one that isn't fixable by pointing to the new location of 3rd party DLLs is:

*The best overloaded method match for 'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.PostProcessNewDynamicQueryEngine
(SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DynamicQueryEngineBase)' has some invalid arguments*

The code it's complaining about (which compiled before, obviously) is in DataAccessAdapter.cs:

```
/// <summary>Creates a new Dynamic Query engine object and passes in the defined catalog/schema overwrite 

hashtables.</summary>
protected override DynamicQueryEngineBase CreateDynamicQueryEngine()
{
    return this.PostProcessNewDynamicQueryEngine(new DynamicQueryEngine());
}
```

This is generated code; here is the unit header for the file (DataAccessAdapter.cs):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is generated code. 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code is generated using LLBLGen Pro version: 3.5
// Code is generated on: Tuesday, April 17, 2012 8:37:28 AM
// Code is generated using templates: SD.TemplateBindings.SharedTemplates.NET20
// Templates vendor: Solutions Design.
// Templates version: 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The DLLs the project is referencing (SD.LLBLGen.Pro.DQE.Access.NET20 and SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses) are Runtime Version v2.0.50727, Version 3.5.0.0

I see that the file was generated over a year ago - do I need to regen this file? If so, how? Is it not getting regenerated because the solution is not at present compiling? If that's the case, it could be a "Catch-22"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that I needed to re-route the path for the assembly reference/DLL. I have two versions installed (3.5 and 4.0), and it was still pointing to 3.5

Comment: Also consider posting llblgen pro related questions to our forums, in case we don't check stackoverflow for llblgen pro related questions ;)

Comment: @Frans: I tried to do that, but the email sent to me with the password to post on the forums never got to me. I'm 99% certain that was "our fault" - the work mail server is very unreliable; I've sent myself many emails from my home account to work account that never showed up. I then have to get them at work by going to my personal "Sent" box. So, perhaps I should have used my reliable email account, but at any rate that explains why I resorted to SO.

Comment: @Frans: The above having been said, I'm still having problems with clashes between the two versions. I'll post another question  about that later this morning (when I get to work).

Comment: @Frans: This is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618219/how-can-i-solve-this-catch-22-between-two-versions-of-llblgenpro

Comment: @Frans: I updated my question there. Also, maybe the email problem *is* in your end, after all, as today I got all the email I had sent myself from home...I would gladly post this on your forum if I could get past that authentication barrier. As an aside (no relation to HTML5), it seems to me a waste of time and a sign of irrational paranoia (is there any other kind?) when companies require authentication to post on their forums. How many people are really going to post on such an arcane forum unless they are "legit"? I can see keeping bots out, but people? Nah...